C++ comparison with integer overflow
int a = 2147483647; // 2^31 - 1
  if (a + 1 > a) {
    cout << "a + 1 is greater than a\n";
  } else {
    cout << "a + 1 is less than a\n";
  }

My IDE: Codeblocks 20.03
a + 1 overflows. But why that condition was return false.
So it printed "a + 1 is less than a".
Why ??? Someone can explain for me.

Signed integer overflow leads to undefined behavior.

On a different note, why the rcpp tag? Nothing in the question or the code is related to R or integrating C++ into R.

In another complier, I got "a + 1 is greater than a".

@Justin You have to understand that integer in R is int in C or more precisely int32_t.  You are hitting the range limit of those four bytes.  No more. no less, and identicaly in any programming languages where you use a four-byte signed integer.  Fundamentally this is a compiler (or in R's case, interpreter) issue which is also 100% orthogonal to which IDE you type this in.

@Justin This is why it's undefined behaviour. Compiler is free to do absolutely anything with such code and will still be valid C++ compiler.

You should not edit a question in a way that invalidates existing answers. If you made a mistake and did not ask the question you intended to, you can delete this question and enter a new one.

a+1 is the issue. Whether you compare < or > is secondary

Your else text is wrong.  It should be less than or equal.

My IDE: Codeblocks 20.03 Your compiler is what's important. Code::Blocks is not a compiler. On MS Windows some of the downloads include compilers but not all. On other OSs Code::Blocks doesn't bundle with a compiler but it uses the system compiler.

You can try to compile with compiler option -fwrapv, that is available on both GCC and Clang. I have enabled it on our own company code base. With it, the overflow of signed integer becomes defined.

The comments about undefined behavior are correct, put are a purist perspective.  In all likelihood, a+1 is evaluating to -2147483648 (32-bit signed wrap around).  And -2147483648 is definitely less than +2147483647.  If you add a cout << (a+1) statement, you'll probably see what's going on. Of course, all of this is undefined behavior.... And compilers, especially with optimizations turned on, are free to make an optimization such that a+1 > a always evaluates to true.

undefined behavior means anything can happen


But why that condition was return false.

First, you do not know that the > evaluated to false. You may have seen the program print “a + 1 is less than a”, but that does not mean the condition evaluated to false. If all of the behavior were defined, then you could deduce from its output what happened inside the program. However, because there is overflow, the behavior is not defined by the C++ standard. The output could have occurred because the program jumped over the instructions to perform the evaluation for the > or for other reasons. So you do not know that the > evaluation was performed at all. Once the behavior is not defined, you do not have a specification for what steps the program goes through, so you do not have the information you need to deduce what happened.
However, one common reason a + 1 > a will evaluate to false is that the compiler will generate an instruction for a + 1 that wraps modulo 232 (when 32-bit int is in use). So adding 2,147,483,647 and 1 will wrap to −2,147,483,648. Then comparing −2,147,483,648 to 1 will produce a “less than” condition, meaning > will evaluate to false.
Another possible reason is that the optimizer can see the value of a is 2,147,483,647, and no int expression has a defined value greater than that (again assuming 32-bit int is in use), and therefore the expression E > a, for any subexpression E, may be assumed to be false. So the optimizer will simply eliminate the > expression at compile time and leave only the code for cout << "a + 1 is less than a\n";.
On the other hand, a reason the evaluation could return true is the  target architecture may have 64-bit general processor registers, so the compiler loads 32-bit int values into 64-bit registers (with sign extension) and does 64-bit arithmetic with them. Then the add of 2,147,483,647 and 1 produces 2,147,483,648, after which the comparison of 2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647 produces a “greater than” condition, meaning > will evaluate to true.
Or the optimizer could see that a + 1 > a is mathematically true for any a, so it could have ignored overflow and eliminated > expression at compile time, leaving only the code for the true case.
All of these options conform to the requirements of the C++ standard, since the fact the behavior is not defined means there are no requirements.

ohh sorry. I typed wrong condition. It must be a + 1 < a.

You answered your own question. it is because it overflowed.
it is like a vintage audio cassette tape counter, after 999 the next number is 000 again.
so 2147483647 + 1 = -2147483648

Only unsigned addition wraps around like that. Signed overflow doesn't follow modulo math and invokes undefined behavior

@phuclv still whatever garbage value you receive for (a+1), wouldn't it be less than a ?
since a is max_int?

@Rishabh_KT it's irrelevant. Once UB occurs anything can happen, including deleting all your data or making nasal daemons flying out of your nose. The variable might not receive any value at all

@phuclv As I already mentioned in a previous comment, Clang and GCC do have a compiler flag -fwrapv that makes the behavior well-defined, signed integers just wrap like in this answer.

unsigned integers do not overflow. they wrap around. Thats similar to your tape recorder example, from the biggest number it wraps around to the smallest. Signed integers do not wrap around, they overflow.
